# On Button click replace FlatList item to the next in the array

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

On button click, I would like the `FlatList` to show the next item in the array.

I understand button currently keep **"adding"** to the `FlatList` intead of **"replacing"** the existing content, could not figure out how to replace the currently loaded item with the next in the array.

For instance if "John Doe1" is what is currently loaded, on button click it should changed to "John Doe2".

Much appreciate if someone could please point me in the right direction on how to achieve this?

Here's what I've done so far.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList, Button } from 'react-native';
const Showme = () => {
    const [display, setDisplay] = useState(1);

    const managedList = [
        {name : "John Doe1"},
        {name : "John Doe2"},
        {name : "John Doe3"},
        {name : "John Doe4"},
        {name : "John Doe5"},
        {name : "John Doe12"},
        {name : "John Doe13"},
        {name : "John Doe14"},
        {name : "John Doe15"}

    ];
    return(
        <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
        <FlatList
            data={managedList.slice(managedList, display)}
            keyExtractor={ mohan => mohan.name}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
                return <Text style={styles.menuStyle}>{item.name}</Text>
            }}
        />

        <Button 
            title="Show Next"
            onPress={() => {
                setDisplay(display + 1);
            }}
        />
        </View>
    );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    menuStyle:{
        borderWidth: 1,
        padding: 40,
        flex: 1
    }
})
export default Showme;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

change your flastlist to this,

```
<FlatList
  data={managedList.slice(display - 1, display)}
  keyExtractor={ mohan => mohan.name}
  renderItem={({ item }) => {
    return <Text style={styles.menuStyle}>{item.name}</Text>
  }}
/>
```

Your slicing starts from index 0 which is index 0 to whatever value you add to it.